# Tooltip issue on adjacent Highchart charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

An issue I have noticed when you put two charts side by side in highcharts is that the tooltip function will work for the first chart but not the other. My guess that is that although the charts "look" like they are next to each other ... but in fact chart 1 is actually on top of chart 2. A good example of this is as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/F3pts/7/

Other example that will yield the same issue:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        animation: true
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        width :320,

    }, {
        type: 'datetime',
        offset: 0,
        width :200,
        left: 380
    }],

    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 2,
        offset: 0,
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
           ],

    series: [{
        xAxis: 0,
        name: 'Some line',
        data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 7],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 5],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 6],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 4],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 5]
        ],
    }, {
        name: 'bar1',
        xAxis: 1,
        data: [

                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 5],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 6],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 7],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 4],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 4]

        ],

    }, {
        name: 'bar2',
        xAxis: 1,
        data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 5],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 8],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 5],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 6],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 4],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 3]
        ],
    }]
};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Any ideas as to how ALL tooltips can be displayed? Kinda defeats the purpose if only one of these is available...

Regards and thanks for your time

Comment: Hasn't exactly answered your question, but I don't think the line graph is hiding the other graphs. you can still hover over them and see the tool tip appear: http://jsfiddle.net/F3pts/52/... I guess you just need to play around with it a bit more.

Comment: Hello Mike :) Am not sure what the problem is and I have messed around with it for quite some time which is why I am posting a question! You are right to say though that you can still select the curves "behind" the other graph -so perhaps the issue is limited to Tooltip. Is this a highcharts bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tooltip doesn't work, because of missconfigured chart:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: function () {
        return "";
    }
},
```

pointFormat should be string, not a function.

Anyway, there is stil la problem with tooltip position, see [#2062](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2062).